# wxPython: automatic search of UltimateListCtrl while typing

Tags: wxpython

Is there a way to make an `UltimateListCtrl` automatically search one of its columns when the user types, like common native list controls?

To clarify, suppose we have a list:

```
+---------+--------+--------+
| Key Col | Data 1 | Data 2 |
+---------+--------+--------+
| foo       1        2      |
| bar       3        4      |
| baz       5        6      |
| foobar    7        8      |
+---------+--------+--------+
```

and the second row has the focus.  If the user types "f" (or "foo"), I'd like the focus to jump to the fourth row (the next one in the list with a prefix that matches the typed string).  If the second row had focus and instead the user typed "baz", it should jump to the third row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always add such a method by binding to key presses and and moving a highlight yourself.